# How can I transfer all my Web/Software development files,databases onto a new computer without having to reconfigure everything

Tags: windows-10, laptop, data-transfer

I was wondering Is there a way I can transfer all my coding files , databases , software and stuff from one laptop (Windows 10) to another without having to reconfigure everything. I heard that disk cloning is a way to do it. Sorry guys I'm new to the coding stuff , I don't want to install everything again such as wamp , laravel as well as configure everything again on command prompt ,etc etc. If there is a solution please let me know. Appreciate it.

Thanks Regards

Comment: Disk cloning may just cause you trouble in other ways if the hardware on the new computer is significantly different. It would copy all of the drivers and hardware-specific information in Windows too.

Comment: So what do you suggest then? My old and new laptops have SSD'S. So transferring data from one SSD to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Clonezilla to clone your system.  [Here is a tutorial on how to use it](https://youtu.be/yQ9NpWZ74BU), and you can download it [here](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php).

Comment: I don't think physically could be the way because most new laptops it's almost impossible to take out the SSD. My both new and older laptops have SSD'S so trying to transfer data from one SSD to another.

Comment: Did you try, I was able to do it on three different laptops from three different companys. (HP, Dell, Lenovo)

Answer (score 0):

And after using Clonezilla you need to run [SysPrep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11). It is a Microsoft tool that will wipe drivers from Windows, while keeping all your software and tools installed.

After plugin a drive, the Windows will essentially download and install all new drivers (it is exactly as it is in the state after system installation - but again, no custom software will be lost).

If you change GPU manufactor (ie. GeForce into Radeon), you will need to use also [DDU](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) (Display Driver Uninstall).

Last thing - Windows is anxious about having the same OS cloned in the same network. You *may* encounter permission problems if you plug in both PC to the same LAN segment.

Comment: Modern Windows (7 and newer) reacts reasonably well to being transplanted over to new hardware. Running sysprep may not be necessary.